# Display PHP Errors Within a Requested Page

Tags: php, ajax, debugging

I have a some Ajax on a PHP page which requests another PHP page a bunch of times to process part numbers and return certain information. The only problem is when I accidentally make some sort of PHP error on the page it is requesting I have no idea of knowing what I did wrong on the PHP page because the console just returns "undefined" when I try to use console.log(response.my_var); to print response variables in the console. How do I debug my PHP page that is being requested? I cannot seem to get the PHP to return any errors, it just crashes and JavaScript returns those undefined response variables. Is there a way for me to access the PHP errors that should be being generated? Here is the Ajax Request Code I am using:

```
function imagething(){
if(!done) {
    var url = "process_parts.php";

    $.ajax({
        //async: false, defaults to async
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            parts: parts,
            part_delimiter: part_delimiter,
            diagram_format: diagram_format
        } 
    }).done(function(response) {
        //This is what produces "undefined"--> console.log(response.part_delimiter);
        if (response.processed !== limit) {
            // asked to process 20, only processed <=19 - there aren't any more
            done = true;
        }
        if(response.table_data != '') {
            $('#myTable > tbody:last').append(response.table_data);
        }
        if(response.image_format != '') {
            $('#third_th').append(" (format: "+response.image_format+")");
            $('#fourth_th').append(" (format: "+response.diagram_format+")");
            $('#fifth_th').append(" (format: "+response.pdf_format+")");
        }
        offset += response.processed;
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({'placement': 'top'});
        $("#mybox").html("<span class=\"color_blue\">Processed a total of " + offset + " parts.</span>");
        imagething(); //<--------------------------recursive call
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {

        $("#mybox").html("Error after processing " + offset + " parts. Error: " + textStatus);

        done = true;
    });
}
}
imagething();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways to do this.
Firstly you can use Google Chrome and press Ctrl+Shift+I... now click on the Network tab and you can view the send/response values easily of your ajax calls.
You can even echo/print out in your ajax PHP if necessary.
Personally I copy and paste this ajax URL request into another window to view the response this way (usually with an extra GET variable such as _debug=1 defined.

You can also do it via CURL requests, again capture the CURL command from the Google Chrome Network page ('Copy as CURL command')

Finally you can use a network sniffer such as Charles Proxy to intercept traffic if you can't use Chrome.